# Check if array columns have overlapping element

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with two array columns, looking as follows:

```
Arrayed_Column_1
[{"ID":222222,"No":2},{"ID":333333,"No":1}]
[{"ID":555555,"No":2},{"ID":333333,"No":1},{"ID":333333,"No":3}]
[{"ID":222222,"No":2},{"ID":555555,"No":1},{"ID":333333,"No":3}]
[{"ID":555555,"No":2},{"ID":333333,"No":1}]

Arrayed_Column_2
[{"ID":333333,"No":2},{"ID":666663,"No":1}]
[{"ID":333333,"No":2},{"ID":666666,"No":1},{"ID":333333,"No":3}]
[{"ID":222222,"No":2},{"ID":555555,"No":1},{"ID":333333,"No":3}]
[{"ID":555333,"No":2},{"ID":66666,"No":1}]
```

How can filter on those rows in which a combination of an ID and No of column_1 are also present in column_2 without using the `explode` function?

I know the `array_contains` function but this only checks for particular values.

Comment: What is the type of `Arrayed_Column_1`? Array of Maps?

Comment: It's an array with structured elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`arrays_overlap`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_overlap):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

col1 = F.expr('transform(column_1, x -> struct(x.ID as ID, x.No as No, x.Value2 as Value2))')
col2 = F.expr('transform(column_2, x -> struct(x.ID as ID, x.No as No, x.Value2 as Value2))')

df2 = df.filter(F.arrays_overlap(col1, col2))
```

Another way is to check `array_intersect`:

```
df2 = df.filter(F.size(F.array_intersect(col1, col2)) != 0)
```

Comment: Seems this works fine but I get a data type mismatch notification: Column_1 contains an additional element which is not present in Column_2

Comment: it is an array struc. I already see where the mismatch is coming from. column1 contains a boolean value (which we actually don't need for this comparison):
    Column_1:array
    element:struct
       ID:long
       No:long
       Value1:boolean
       Value2:string

    Column_2:array
    element:struct
       ID:long
       No:long
       Value2:string

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `exists` + `array_contains`:

```
df1 = df.filter(
    "exists(Arrayed_Column_1, x -> array_contains(Arrayed_Column_2, x))"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It does work, but still had to make some adjustments in the array structure. With help of the other answer I managed to work this out. Thanks for your help as well!